# How can I prevent errors when opening the front camera in swift?

Tags: swift

I am trying to open front camera in swift
Sometimes an error occurs when opening the camera in the firebase crashlytics logo.
The log is as follows

'EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000102b2e114'

I'm trying to solve the problem but it didn't solve the problem
I have never had an error occur on my device.
Is there anything wrong with my code? The code is below

```
    func startCamera()
    {
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession.sessionPreset = .high
        
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(
                    deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera],
                    mediaType: .video,
                    position: .unspecified
                )
        
        for device in deviceDiscoverySession.devices {
                    switch device.position {
                    case .front:
                        frontCamera = device
                    case .back:
                        backCamera = device
                    default:
                        break
                    }
            }
        
        do {
            
            if let fcamera = frontCamera {

            } else {
                frontCamera = getCamera(with: .front)
            }
            
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: frontCamera!)
            
            stillImageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

            if captureSession.canAddInput(input) && captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
                captureSession.addInput(input)
                captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
                setupLivePreview()
            }
        }
        catch let error  {
            print("Error Unable to initialize back camera:  \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you call `startRunning`?

Comment: What is `getCamera(with: .front)`? Does it return an optional camera? Since you do a force unwrap just afterward...